# Can't get animated link hover working with Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

Hi I'm trying to get an animation working when I hover over links with Nextjs and Tailwind. Anything would help thanks

Example of the working code in standard CSS/HTML

```
<div class="link-cont">
  <div class="link-wrapper">
    <a class="link hover-1" href="#">#1 - left to right</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.link-cont {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.link-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.hover-1 {
  &:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: @red;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
  &:hover {
      &:after {
        transform-origin: bottom left;
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
}
```

}

My code in tailwind

```
      <div className="">
    <Link href="/models">
      <a className="
      ml-auto
      font-serif
      text-6xl
      inline-block
      relative
      no-underline
      px-[10px]
      after:absolute
      after:w-[100%]
      after:h-[5px]
      after:bg-black
      after:bottom-0
      after:left-0
      after:scale-x-0
      after:origin-bottom-right
      after:transition-transform
      hover:after:origin-bottom-left
      hover:after:scale-x-1
      ">
        models
      </a>
    </Link>
    <Link href="/contact">
      <a className="mx-10 font-serif text-6xl">contact</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
```

Not sure if this is bugging out from the after and hover states but you should be able to stack pseudo selectors and stuff as per the tailwind docs. Don't really know what's wrong with the code as the after portion of the css does not show up in the inspector.

Comment: Change `hover:after:scale-x-1` into `hover:after:scale-x-100` that's all. Sometimes differences in CSS 0 to 1 scale and Tailwind's 0-100 (like transforms and opacity) may confuse :) [DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RGFfj8drRL)